# Error sending e-mail to internal domains hosted on linux server using sendmail

Tags: debian, sendmail

I currently have sendmail configured on a web server, and only need to send emails for newsletters, contact forms, notifications, any e-mail address using a domain hosted on the server fails to send. We are using another server on a different IP address for e-mail, and I've tried using that as a relay but ran into the same issue. Additionally, the e-mail address is getting replaced with the FQDN.

Before I tried relaying to our mail server, I could successfully send to any domain, but had the same issue with the hostname of the webserver being added the email address (user@domain.com would be changed to user@host1.domain.com)

Here is the current error:
050 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
050 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help. It is my understanding that the server is just seeing the incoming mail as comming from an invalid sender for some reason. The issue with the adding of the hostname is most likely comming from the server not knowing the format you wish to have the mail processed too. Also this might help: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_network_satellite/5.0/html/installation_guide/s1-installation-sendmail. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I'll give that a try. So even though I can receive e-mail sent to the same addresses normal (via e-mail clients, webmail, etc), when it is sent to the mail server from the  web server that e-mail is considered invalid and the problems start?

It would seem like all mail I try to send from the web server would fail, which isn't the case. I can send to say, gmail, through the command line or web application without any issues.

Comment: It looks like the suggestions you mentioned wouldn't apply for me. I already had the changes for sendmail.mc applied and am no using smrsh.

Comment: Sorry I could not help, good luck with finding a fix.

Comment: O in that sendmail.mc file is MAILER(`local') set if not it may be rejecting it based on the fact it looks to be coming from it's self and it is not set to recieve localy.

Comment: This may also help: https://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/05/make-sendmail-accept-mail-from-external-sources/

Comment: The problem isn't that it's rejecting e-mails from the webserver, more so that it is, for some reason, changing the from address and to address after it connects to the mail server and I'm not exactly sure which server is doing it

Comment: Check this out, might help with some of the issue. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Sendmail.html it is older info but the sendmail service has not changed that much.

Comment: I got the mail server successfully configured to accept and send messages to another through to another domain we host but for some reason mail is still being rejected from our main domain. Is this because it is in the configuration files when it shouldn't be?